# Show that $\prod_p1+\frac{1}{p^{4s}}+\frac{1}{p^{5s}}$ converges

Tags: convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I want to show that
$$\prod_p1+\frac{1}{p^{4s}}+\frac{1}{p^{5s}}$$
for the Re(s)$\geq\frac{1}{3}$. ( $p$ prime)
Should I compare it to the Riemann zeta function, although that only converges for Re(s)>1?

Answer (score 1):

Absolute convergence of the infinite product.
Note that $\sum n^a$ converges for $a<-1$ by the integral test.
Let $p_n$ be the $n$th prime.  Let $s>0$ and write $\sigma = \mathrm{Re }(s)$. As $n \to \infty$,
\begin{align}
p_n &\sim n\log n
\\
|p_n^{-4s}| &= p_n^{-4\sigma} \sim n^{-4\sigma}(\log n)^{-4\sigma}
\\
|p_n^{-5s}| &\sim n^{-5\sigma}(\log n)^{-5\sigma}
\\
|p^{-4s}+p^{-5s}| &\sim n^{-4\sigma}(\log n)^{-4\sigma}
\end{align}
This means that series
$$
\sum_n \left(p_n^{-4s}+p_n^{-5s}\right)
$$
converges absolutely if $-4\sigma<-1$, that is $\sigma>1/4$.  Thus the infinite product
$$
\prod_p (1+p_n^{-4s}+p_n^{-5s})
$$
converges absolutely if $\text{Re}(s)>1/4$.

Comment: And by the PNT it converges iff $\Re(s)\ge 1/4,s\ne 1/4$

Comment: How would I show its non-zero and holomorphic for Re(s)≥⅓?

Comment: In a convergent infinite product, where no factor is zero, the product itself is nonzero.  Next, each factor $(1+p_n^{-4s}+p_n^{-5s})$ is holomorphic for $\text{Re}(x) \ge 1/3$, and the infinite product converges uniformly on $\text{Re}{(s) \ge 1/3$.